# New-RDSessionDeployment : Validation failed for the "RD Connection Broker" parameter

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, rds

Tried a billion ways to get this to work and I just can't solve it.

I am trying to configure RDS remotely but it keeps telling me `Unable to connect to the server by using Windows PowerShell remoting`.

I have ran `Enable-PSRemoting -Force -SkipNetworkProfileCheck` but it is still not working.

This is also run on the same server and I have disabled IPv6.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $creds -ScriptBlock {param($srv) New-RDSessionDeployment -ConnectionBroker $srv -WebAccessServer $srv -SessionHost $srv} -ArgumentList $server
Validation failed for the "RD Connection Broker" parameter.
EC2AMAZ-VN782KT.directory.local          Unable to connect to the server by using Windows PowerShell remoting. Verify that you can connect to the server.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,New-RDSessionDeployment
    + PSComputerName        : EC2AMAZ-VN782KT.directory.local
```

I have also tried it this way

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $creds
[EC2AMAZ-VN782KT.directory.local]: PS C:\Users\Admin\Documents> whoami
directory\admin
[EC2AMAZ-VN782KT.directory.local]: PS C:\Users\Admin\Documents> $server = (Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).DNSHostName + "." + (Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).Domain
[EC2AMAZ-VN782KT.directory.local]: PS C:\Users\Admin\Documents> New-RDSessionDeployment -ConnectionBroker $server -WebAccessServer $server -SessionHost $server
New-RDSessionDeployment : Validation failed for the "RD Connection Broker" parameter.
EC2AMAZ-VN782KT.directory.local          Unable to connect to the server by using Windows PowerShell remoting. Verify that you can connect to the server.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-RDSessionDeployment -ConnectionBroker $server -WebAccessServer $s ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,New-RDSessionDeployment
```

However, if I run the following, it works, which tells me remoting is working!

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $creds -ScriptBlock {param($server) Write-Output $server } -ArgumentList '123'
123
```

Comment: No sure if this will help anyone in the future, a big thread on this issue. I gave up and reinstalled the VM. 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bbb7427b-f839-48c4-b49c-467138f94b16/compatibility-problem-when-installing-remote-desktop-services-role-on-2012-quotunable-to-connect?forum=winserver8setup